# Characteristics of odd parts in a partion

Tags: number-theory

Show that the number of partitions of $n$ in which only odd parts may be repeated is equal to the number of partitions of $n$ in which no parts appear more than 3 times.

Comment: Guessing this is a homework question, so I'll give a hint.  Have you seen a proof that the number of partitions with only odd parts is the same as the number of distinct parts, using generating functions?  You can adapt that proof to this problem.